# Calling View Controller Method From TabBarClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a timer running in a tabbar class that saves data to the cloud each time it is called. Then i want it to call a method on the currently select view controller to tell the user what was saved. I am doing this with the following.

```
    if (self.selectedIndex == 1) {
    MessagesViewController *msgView = [[MessagesViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Running");
    [msgView testMethod];

}
```

This is working and the method gets called if its the select tab.

```
NSString *teststring = [formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate];
NSLog(@"%@", teststring);

self.TestLab.text = teststring;
```

The NSlog is showing every time but the label text is not updating. 
I am sure it's simple but i can't come up with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
MessagesViewController *msgView = [[MessagesViewController alloc]init];
```

Allocates a new instance of `MessagesViewController`. It does not give you a reference to the view controller instance that is currently active.  The method is executed on this new instance, so you get the `NSLog` output, but the text field is likely `nil` and at the very least, not on screen.

You can use the `selectedViewController` property of a `UITabBarController` to get the currently selected view controller.

```
if (self.selectedIndex == 1) {
    MessagesViewController *msgView = (MessagesViewController *)self.selectedViewController;
    NSLog(@"Running");
    [msgView testMethod];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what i was looking for. Its now got me thinking if i need to get the current instance of the tabar class from the MessagesViewController is there a similar call to self.selectedViewController?

Comment: `self.parent` should give you the tab bar controller

Comment: Worked also. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Since it's a timer, it might be on another thread? And you can't update UI in any other thread than the Main thread. Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  self.TestLab.text = teststring;
});
```